# Request response not closing after loop ends Python

Tags: python, api, python-requests, batch-processing, response-headers

Why, even after the loop ends, is the request connection still open. I am using reponse.request to get data via API. Since there is a limit , I get the first set of data after which it says limit reached for the next iteration. Details below :

First I create a function that gets data as shown below. Other data processing I have removed as need to fix batch request first so just getting the length of all the API objects for each iteration :

```
def pull_data(Limit_String):
    payload = "Pass the Payload String with Limit_String variable that gets incremented for each iteration"
    headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'text/plain',
        'Connection': 'Close'
    }
    response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload, verify=False, timeout=300)
    length = len(response.text)
    print(Limit_String)
    response.close()
    session.close()
```

Then calling the function as below and increase iteration to pass the next limit. I have checked the iteration works

```
while Length > 113:
    session = requests.Session()
    Limit_String = "\"" + str(start) + "," + str(Increment) + "\""
    pull_data(Limit_String)
    start = Increment
    Increment = Increment + 999
    File_Number = File_Number + 1
```

For the first iteration I get the objects but when the loops iterates for the second time I was expecting that the system would take as a fresh request and provide data for my next iteration and so on so that in the loop I will keep extracting data and overcome limit posed by API. Kindly help.
Code

```
Limit_String = "\"" + str(start) + "," + str(Increment) + "\""
```

I cannot put all the data at once there is limit of 1000 objects so I pull 999 at a time. 1st iteration :- 0.999 2nd iteration :- 999:1998 Each of these iteration should be separate as then I will be under the limit(1000) and will be able to pull data
Second Iteration I get the issue as :

*Limit clause specified must be positive and it should be less than the account limit of 1000 objects.*

Comment: Hi, can you please add more context and the proper code here ? Its very unclear, what you are looping, what is your function etc. Please add more clarity and debugging detaisl

Comment: I just edited my question . let me know if I can put more clarity.
Function just gets data and check length of response that is the code I put in and the then I call the function and increase my batch # after the function gets called. AFter each end of loop I was hoping that the connection closes and the next the specified limit amount of rows I can pull again

Comment: Well instead of being verbose on logic, if you can put the code properly, it would help. You are talking about iterating - where is the loop in the posted code ? You mentioned some function, that also is not in the code here. And, dont use bold-format in code section it will not work, you can add a code comment

Comment: Hello @Kris not sure why but the code in questions showed after while loop. I have edited again. Kindly have a look
Removed Bold and added comments

Comment: Please have a look at the my post again. I have rectified all issues. Let me know what other details I can share.

Comment: What exactly you meant by ? _overcome limit posed by API_ ?

Comment: The code here passes on the payload that I pass for each request. Code Limit_String = "\"" + str(start) + "," + str(Increment) + "\""
I cannot put all the data at once there is limit of 1000 objects so I pull 999 at a time.
1st iteration :0.999
2nd iteration :999:1998
Each of these iteration should be separate as then I will be under the limit(1000) and will be able to pull data

Comment: Well the loop seems to work fine, I doubt there can be issues where you are building the `payload`, which is not evident here. Also, use `request` under a session context like `with requests.Session() as session:` and use `session.post()`

Comment: I have removed the values and put the structure as below :
 "<request API_version=value client=value client_ver=value namespace=value \
          "key=value><Auth><Login><company>value</company><user>value \
          "</user><password>value</password></Login></Auth>
    <Read type=value \
          "method=value limit=></Read>
    </request> ".format(Limit_String)

I feel if there was problem in payload even the first iteration would not have worked but that's working have checked it multiple ways even without loop

Comment: `"".format()` needs a place-holder like `"This is a {}".format("car")` , As far as I see from your comment, there is no placeholder

Comment: I have put the curly brackets:
limit={}></Read> </request> ".format(Limit_String) I guess missed in posting while editing

Comment: Another issue I see is that, the payload seems to be XML. But you are using content type as text/plain where is it might be `application/xml`

Comment: I changed it to 'Content-Type': 'application/xml' didn't work for that as well